# Problem with Rails 7 App with Amazon S3 on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have rails 7 with the Ruby 3.1.1 application, It's using Amazon S3 for storing images, I have added AWS credentials as well on the app. I have deployed the app to Heroku, ran the migration, and added all the environment variables on Heroku, but when I try to access the Heroku link, I get this error:

"missing credentials, provide credentials with one of the following options: (Aws::Sigv4::Errors::MissingCredentialsError)

- :access_key_id and :secret_access_key
- :credentials
- :credentials_provider"

Has anyone ever had this kind of a problem? How did you correct it?

**Storage.yml**

```
test:
  service: Disk
  root: <%= Rails.root.join("tmp/storage") %>

local:
  service: Disk
  root: <%= Rails.root.join("storage") %>


amazon:
  service: S3
  access_key_id: <%= Rails.application.credentials.dig(:aws, :access_key_id) %>
  secret_access_key: <%= Rails.application.credentials.dig(:aws, :secret_access_key) %>
  region: <%= Rails.application.credentials.dig(:aws, :region) %>
  bucket: <%= Rails.application.credentials.dig(:aws, :bucket) %>
```

**development.rb/production.rb**

```
  config.active_storage.service = :amazon
```

**EDITOR="code --wait" rails credentials:edit**

```
aws:
  access_key_id: ******
  secret_access_key: *******
  region: *******
  bucket: *******
```

I have added also a RAILS_MASTER_KEY env var on Heroku but still I get an error.

Comment: Did you run `heroku config:set RAILS_MASTER_KEY=`cat config/master.key` `after you pushed the code to heroku ?

Comment: You saved me! I did not run that, but now it works perfectly!!!. Thanks @ShaherShamroukh

Comment: Great 
made the comment as an answer so if someone had the same problem would find it

Answer (score 2):

For heroku to read the master key you need to run

`heroku config:set RAILS_MASTER_KEY=`cat config/master.key``